# Reading message body from msg file

Tags: perl, outlook

I am using perl's Email::Outlook::Message to parse the outlook msg files.
I had a sample msg file. Content-Type=text/plain
The message body contains some japanese characters.
On parsing the file using the above perl's library, BODY_PLAIN & BODY_HTML were empty.
However BODY_RTF contains compressed rtf bytestream. I am not sure how to decompress and read the content.

Also why doesn't outlook uses content type as text/rtf. Its definately not text/plain

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Mail::Outlook`. That should definitely make your life easier. Check out this [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~duncan/Mail-Outlook-0.23/lib/Mail/Outlook.pm) page for code samples.